# Whenever I try to open a certain file in dream weaver it gives me violation error

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

[Kindly look at this image for better understanding thankyou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyGi0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable "Reopen documents on startup" (Preferences/General).

this is a Windows issues.

Also try to run DreamWeaver run as an admin.